# Spring transaction hangs for iptables command

Tags: spring, connection, iptables, pool

As part of error handling for our processes, we have tried to disable the communication between the process to the database machine listener port using the following iptables command

```
 iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --destination-port <database-listener-port> -s <database-host-ip> -j DROP
```

However, this cause the process to get stuck with the following log coming from AbstractPlatformTransactionManager::getTransaction

```
 DEBUG:  Creating new transaction with name [<Transaction-Name>]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT; ''
```

Enabling it, later on with 'iptables -F' makes the transaction 'get back to life' again and the connection is being retrieved and ends successfully.

We are most concern with the fact all connection timeout configuration were not activated (?) and therefore we so such hangs, none of our connection pool defaults (see below) has such infinite timeout (we tried  also giving a small default for the abandonedConnectionTimeout but it didn't help and we returned for the true default we believe should be in production) and we expected some kind of cancel operation should be performed.

```
abandonedConnectionTimeout=0
acquireIncrement=5
acquireRetryAttempts=3
checkoutTimeout=5000
idleConnectionTestPeriod=60
inactivityTimeout=1800
inactivityTimeoutforNonUsedConnection=1800
validateConnection=true
```

Thanks for any assist on this matter.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with this database in general, and its timeout configuration in particular, but have you considered modifying the `iptables` rule to reply with an ICMP unreachable packet (or something of that sort) rather than dropping the incoming packet altogether? Also, are you adding the rule after the TCP connection was established? Does each transaction invoke a new TCP connection or try to use an already established one?

Comment: Thanks for trying to help out with this. Appreciated. 
We are using spring transaction management over c3p0 connection pool implementation. It seems like something goes wrong with this specific command. Should we not expect such behaviour in real network connection lost? Otherwise, we would expect the connection pool timeout setup be called somehow and cancel the operation.