# c3p0 checkout out connection hangs for iptables command

Tags: c3p0

following a previous question I had regarding spring & iptables command [Spring transaction hangs for iptables command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26417384/spring-transaction-hangs-for-iptables-command?noredirect=1#comment41489097_26417384)

I found out that it was an issue with the getConnection functionality, where idle-connection is mixed with checkout-connection test when using the following command

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --destination-port <database-listener-port> -s <database-host-ip>
```

In the java documentation for BasicResourcePool class I see there indeed might be such an issue. and that is exactly where I get such infinite loop

```
private synchronized Object prelimCheckoutResource( long timeout )
...
// this is a hack -- but "doing it right" adds a lot of complexity, and collisions between
// an idle check and a checkout should be relatively rare. anyway, it should work just fine.
if ( idleCheckResources.contains( resc ) )
```

My question, will such concern (where packet is being DRP-ed) is expected to be fixed in the code or do you believe running such command is mistake and when database host is not available we can simulate with another command that is more expected in the real world.

Appreciate your input.

Answer (score 0):

so you are presenting c3p0 with an unusual and challenging failure mode here. the idle checks are not failing. nor are they succeeding. they are hanging indefinitely while you are forcing incoming packets to be dropped. (i'm presuming that you use the full command from the [earlier post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26417384/spring-transaction-hangs-for-iptables-command?noredirect=1#comment41489097_26417384), which specifies to drop incoming packets.) c3p0 expects tests to either succeed or fail with an Exception in a reasonable time. hanging presents challenges.

you can work around those challenges somewhat by setting the c3p0 config param [maxAdministrativeTaskTime](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#maxAdministrativeTaskTime) checkoutTimeout unfortunately won't help: it only times out clients wait()ing on unavailable Connections, it's not designed to notice clients stuck in never-ending, hung tests.

note that this failure mode you are creating does not resemble how a typical database outage would present itself. in a real database outage, the test of the idle Connection would fail immediately with an Exception as the outgoing tcp Connection was refused.

note also that the config in your previous question does not much resemble valid c3p0 config. it looks like you are mixing config params from different pools, and it's not clear that the params you are setting is even getting to your pool. when c3p0 pools initialize, they dump config information to your logs at INFO. please check that and make sure that the configuration dumped by the pool is the one you intended to set.

Comment: Yes. the naming of the configuration differ as those configuration are the ones we expose in our wrapping library to initialize a c3p0DataSource bean in spring (e.g., abandonedConnectionTimeout refer to unreturnedConnectionTimeout).

Comment: that said, I appreciate your comment that such behavior does not resemble real world situation and we shouldn't expect it in database failures. (its own connectivity or the host on which it runs). We will try the maxAdministrativeTaskTime and update this thread if it helps in such unusual mode. Thanks for your valued time.

Comment: You were right about the maxAdministrativeTask, trying to set it to a smaller value didn't return the connection from hanging.